# call a function after closing tab/browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is it possible to delete localStorage data/logout after closing tab/browser window but not for refreshing that page of the project. So cause if some closes it, user have to login again.
Thanks

Comment: Try [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead.

Comment: Or look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: "window.onbeforeunload" working but also in refresh the  page. page may be refresh again again but should not be remove my storage Data for the refresh page.
function should only call while close the tab/windows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
localStorage.setItem("someVar","someValue");
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  localStorage.removeItem("someVar");
};
```

But it's better sessionStorage

```
 sessionStorage.setItem("someVar","someValue");
```

When user leaves the page all items are removed

Comment: yes !
I did this but this is happening for also refreshing that page.

Comment: So, you should .setItem when document load and remove it when onbeforeunload, because there is no tab close event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete anything on close of tab use `sessionStorage` rather  than `localStorage` as:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("key","value");
```

Comment: hey sorry, it should be `sessionStorage` I typed incorrectly. Updated the answer.

Comment: `sessionStorage` does the same, where and how you are trying? Please add your code as well.

Comment: // window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        //    sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
        //     return '';
        // };
at my app.run section

Comment: @BishnuKumarBhakat there is no need of `onbeforeunload` when you use `sessionStorage`, just set your user data in `sessionStorage` after login that's it.

Comment: hmmm,
Right, happen,
thnaks for your kind Info. it's another way to do some kind of.

Comment: @BishnuKumarBhakat If this answer helped you, you can upvote/accept the answer. :)